# Can an airline legally claim its tickets are feely changeable if their customer service can't be reached within some "reasonable" amount of time?

Tags: united-states, consumer-protection, air-travel

For my last vacation, I bought a flight ticket from an airline. The ticket was changeable without any fee. However, to change it, I had to call the airline's customer support and nobody was picking up the phone within 3 hours.

This made me wonder: Are airlines allowed to claim that their tickets are feely changeable if their customer service can't be reached to change the ticket within some "reasonable" amount of time?

I am interested in the case that the ticket was purchased in the United States, and departing from the United States.

Comment: What is *reasonable* for the airline?

Comment: Did you make any attempt to rule out technical or other short-term issues like a faulty phone line or temporary staffing shortage by trying again on a different day and/or time of day?

Comment: Apparently they can. Your story proves it.

Comment: @JohnFx you know what I meant

Comment: @Trish the law could specify it

Comment: @brhans yes, called via different phone lines and tried on different days far apart.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt those would be **state** consumer protection laws, if they exist.

Comment: @Trish Thanks interesting there are no federal consumer protection laws? Indeed in my birth country, France, that'd be in the consumer protection laws.

Comment: there are only *very* few federal ones, most of the US has consumer protection laws on state level. Incidentally... air travel has some federal regulations from the U.S. Department of Transportation:  https://www.transportation.gov/airconsumer

Comment: @Trish Got it. Which state matters? e.g., caller's state, airline's HQ state, etc. Good to know about the federal regulations for air travel. True, I know there's the "Cancelling or refunding a ticket within 24-hours of booking" rule.

Comment: @Trish I'll contact them via https://www.transportation.gov/contact-us when I get a chance. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

Airlines in the US are allowed to make this claim, since it is true, i.e. not deceptive. If an airline refused to make changes or as a practice made it impossible to make changes, there might be a potential action for deceptive advertising.

There is a separate question here, whether an airline has an obligation to refund money if "technical difficulties" make it impossible for them to process your claim in a timely manner. This [guidance document](https://www.transportation.gov/sites/dot.gov/files/docs/Notice_24hour_hold_final20130530_0.pdf) from the DOT should lead you to check [14 CFR Part 259](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-II/subchapter-A/part-259), which confirms that the reservation can be cancelled within 24 hours. Nothing in the wording of the regulation suggests that this is limited to "customers who succeed in cancelling". So perhaps they may believe that you failed to try to request a refund within the required time period, and will deny the refund on that basis. Then you file a complaint, and the DoT decides whether it is more likely that they were swamped, or that you didn't try to get a refund in a timely manner.